# Why am I getting an empty body as response from HTTP request Noe.js

Tags: node.js, json, httprequest

so I am trying to send a http request to a server and as response I should get the body where all the information I need is in. When I then try to .parseJSON() the body I get an exception telling me that my body is empty. There is no way that the body is really empty so there has to be a mistake in the code.
I can not give you the whole code because of passwords and stuff like that.
Code:

```
public addVehicle(): Promise<void>{
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            url: [URL],
            method: "POST",
        
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': [user/psw],
                'token': [authToken]
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'vehicleID': vehicleID,
                'externalID': externalID,
                'brandID': vehicleBrandId,
                'modelGroupID': vehicleModelId,
                'typeName': typeName,
                'segmentationID': vehicleSegmentationId,
                'categoryID': vehicleCategoryId,
                'fuelTypeID': vehicleFuelTypeId,
                'transmissionTypeID': vehicleTransmissionTypeId,
                'propulsionTypeID': vehiclePropulsionTypeId,
                'registerationDate': registerationDate,
                'powerKW': powerKW,
                'description': description
            })
            
            
            
          }

          let req = request.post(options, (err, res, body) => {
           let rawAuth = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(body);

                resolve();
                
            })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `JSON.stringify()`.
I am assuming that your receiving API expects the fields in the body. Sending the data as string will hide the fields from the receiving API. It will just see one string object (not sure what the key will be tho).

```
const options = {
            url: [URL],
            method: "POST",
        
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': [user/psw],
                'token': [authToken]
            },
            body: {
                'vehicleID': vehicleID,
                'externalID': externalID,
                'brandID': vehicleBrandId,
                'modelGroupID': vehicleModelId,
                'typeName': typeName,
                'segmentationID': vehicleSegmentationId,
                'categoryID': vehicleCategoryId,
                'fuelTypeID': vehicleFuelTypeId,
                'transmissionTypeID': vehicleTransmissionTypeId,
                'propulsionTypeID': vehiclePropulsionTypeId,
                'registerationDate': registerationDate,
                'powerKW': powerKW,
                'description': description
            }
          }
```